# Envio de Email está saindo o path dos anexos no corpo do e-mail

Tags: c#, .net, envio-de-email

gostaria de uma ajuda! fiz uma classe para envio de e-mails em minha aplicação, onde será gerado relatórios para serem enviados em formato PDF e XML, porém o e-mail está sendo enviado com o path dos arquivos no corpo do e-mail. e em meu codigo nao existe nenhuma ação onde isso é feito.

Alguém tem alguma ideia do que pode ser?

```
using System;
using CSharpUtil.Validation;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using System.Net.Security;
using System.IO;

namespace CSharpUtil.Services
{
    public class Email
    {
        protected MailMessage Mail = new MailMessage();

        public bool Send(string fromName, string from, string to, string cc, string co, string subject, string body,
                         string attachments, string user, string password, string smtpHost, int port, int autentication, int enableSsl)
        {

            if (!AssertConsern.AssertArgumentIsNullorEmpty(from.Trim(),
                    "Por favor informe o e-mail do remetente!", "Envio de Email")) return false;
            if (!AssertConsern.AssertArgumentIsNullorEmpty(password,
                    "Por favor informe a senha do e-mail do remetente!", "Envio de Email")) return false;
            if (!AssertConsern.AssertArgumentIsNullorEmpty(smtpHost,
                    "Por favor informe DNS do provedor SMTP/IMAP do e-mail do remetente!", "Envio de Email")) return false;
            if (!AssertConsern.AssertArgumentIsNullorEmpty(port,
                    "Por favor informe a porta do provedor SMTP/IMAP do e-mail do remetente!", "Envio de Email")) return false;
            if (!AssertConsern.AssertArgumentIsNullorEmpty(new object[] { to, cc, co },
                    "Por favor informe o e-mail do destinatário!", "Envio de Email")) return false;

            try
            {

                Mail.From = new MailAddress(from.Trim(), fromName.Trim());
                EmailAdd(to.Trim());
                EmailAdd(cc.Trim());
                EmailAdd(co.Trim());
                Mail.Subject = subject.Trim();
                Mail.SubjectEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
                Mail.Body = body.TrimEnd();
                Mail.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
                Mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
                Mail.Priority = MailPriority.High;
                attachments = attachments.Trim();

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(attachments))
                {
                    char[] characters = new[] { ';', ','};

                    foreach (var attachment in attachments.Split(characters))
                   {
                        if (!File.Exists(attachment.Trim())) continue;

                        FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(attachment.Trim(), FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
                        Attachment data = new Attachment(fileStream, Path.GetFileName(attachment));
                        Mail.Attachments.Add(data);

                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Falha na tentativa de criação do e-mail! " +
                               "Verifique as configurações e tente novamente!\n\n" + ex.Message, "Envio de E-mail");
                return false;
            }


            try
            {
                var smtp = new SmtpClient(smtpHost, port);
                smtp.EnableSsl = (enableSsl == 1 ? true : false);
                if (autentication > 0)
                    smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(user.Trim(), password.Trim());

                smtp.Send(Mail);
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Falha no envio do e-mail! " +
                                "Verifique as configurações e tente novamente!\n\n" + ex.Message,"Envio de Email");
                return false;
            }
        }

        private void EmailAdd(string email)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(email))
            {
                foreach (var sTo in email.Split(';')
                    .Where(sTo => sTo != null && email.Trim() != ""))
                    Mail.To.Add(sTo);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Como a variável `body` está sendo preenchida? E se você mudar, só para teste, em vez de passar a variável `body` real passar uma constante, como `"eu sou um corpo de teste"` para ver se o comportamento continua o mesmo?

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado obrigado pela dica! descobri o problema. e realmente o problema estava na entrada do dado. O que acontece é o seguinte essa classe de e-mail foi escrita em C# para ser consumida por uma outra linguagem legada através de uma DLL COM gerada pelo NuGet "Unmanaged Exports". Para resumir a novela o problema estava em um BUG da linguagem que estava consumindo a DLL e até agora nao entendi por que motivo ela estava concatenando o valor das duas variáveis... mas resolvi de outra forma contornando esse problema. Resumindo, foi pau de linguagem legado!

Comment: Caso tenha a curiosidade de saber qual linguagem estou falando, estou utilizando clarion 5.5 da softvelocity.